# Apache POI Password-Protect Large 2GB PowerPoint File

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to password-encrypt very large PPTX files (2GB) using Apache POI.  How can I use Apache POI Standard Encryption to encrypt 2GB PPTX files (there are many videos embedded in the PowerPoint)?

I've set `IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` (to the maximum allowed value) and also played around with other [large file configurations](https://poi.apache.org/components/configuration.html):

```
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(-1.0);
ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.setThresholdBytesForTempFiles(50000000);
ZipPackage.setUseTempFilePackageParts(true);
```

Regardless, I'm getting the same **exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException: Can't allocate an array > 2147483647
        at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.safelyAllocateCheck(IOUtils.java:559)
        at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.safelyAllocate(IOUtils.java:547)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.ByteArrayBackedDataSource.extend(ByteArrayBackedDataSource.java:86)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.ByteArrayBackedDataSource.write(ByteArrayBackedDataSource.java:63)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.createBlockIfNeeded(POIFSFileSystem.java:493)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSStream$StreamBlockByteBuffer.createBlockIfNeeded(POIFSStream.java:272)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSStream$StreamBlockByteBuffer.write(POIFSStream.java:294)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentOutputStream.write(DocumentOutputStream.java:144)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentOutputStream.write(DocumentOutputStream.java:124)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:137)
        at org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndianOutputStream.write(LittleEndianOutputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:410)
        at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:387)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.standard.StandardEncryptor$StandardCipherOutputStream.processPOIFSWriterEvent(StandardEncryptor.java:201)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSDocument.<init>(POIFSDocument.java:112)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode.createDocument(DirectoryNode.java:380)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.standard.StandardEncryptor$StandardCipherOutputStream.writeToPOIFS(StandardEncryptor.java:185)
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.standard.StandardEncryptor$StandardCipherOutputStream.close(StandardEncryptor.java:175)
        at Program.encryptPPTXFile(Program.java:108)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
try(POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem()) {
    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
    Encryptor encryptor = info.getEncryptor();
    encryptor.confirmPassword(password);

    // Read in an existing OOXML file and write to encrypted output stream
    try (OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(inputPath);
        OutputStream os = encryptor.getDataStream(fs)) {
        opc.save(os);
    }

    // Write out the encrypted version
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)) {
        fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
    }

    System.out.println("Document successfully encrypted");

} catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException | InvalidFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If there was a way to ignore the byte-array size limits or save this in chunks, it could solve the problem.  But haven't found anything on this.

Comment: Try forking POI and changing POIFSFileSystem to use a FileBackedDataSource instead of a ByteArrayBackedDataSource. Byte Arrays can only support 2Gb but files can support much larger data sets.

Comment: POI already has TempFilePOIFSFileSystem - use this instead of POIFSFileSystem. It should support larger data than POIFSFileSystem.

Comment: So I found some history and it traces back to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658495/apache-poi-encrypting-xlsx-file-greater-than-2gb-fails - it seems like TempFilePOIFSFileSystem is not likely to be enough. POI uses ints to track size and these are likely to overflow when the data is too big.

Comment: There have been a few code changes since that previous issue - so it might still be worth trying TempFilePOIFSFileSystem to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you! `TempFilePOIFSFileSystem` worked for file-size upwards of 3GB. You can add this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POI 5.2.3 has TempFilePOIFSFileSystem - a subclass of POIFSFileSystem. TempFilePOIFSFileSystem should be used when encrypting very large files. POIFSFileSystem uses a byte array to process the data and this can only handle 2Gb of decompressed data.